# Intellij IDEA Plugin Gradle development - generating code to an existing class

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, plugins

I'm working on my IDEA IntelliJ Plugin with gradle and I am trying to create a button that adds a function to the current class, or a given class.
I saw an example in Eclipse but couldn't find the equivalent libraries.

I've tried to seek for an equivalent library to ICompilationUnit in Eclipse but couldn't find anything

ICompilationUnit unit = compilationUnit(activeEditor());

```
    final String messageName = inputBox("Create New Message",
            "Message Name");

    if (messageName == null)
        return null;
    String camel = camelCase(messageName);
    final String methodName = "handle" + camel;

    IType type = null;
    try {
        unit.createImport(Global.WHEN_RECEIVED_CLASS_NAME.<String>data(), null, null);
        type = unit.getType(drop(unit.getElementName(), 4));

        if (!type.getSuperclassName().equals("SimpleAgent")) {
            msgbox("cannot create message - unrecognized agent type");
            return null;
        }

        IMethod mtd = method(type, methodName);

        if (mtd == null) {
            mtd = type
                    .createMethod(
                            "@WhenReceived(\""
                                    + messageName
                                    + "\")\npublic void "
                                    + methodName
                                    + "(){\n\t//TODO: Add Message Handling Code Here.\n\t"
                                    + "//you can add any parameters to the method in order to receive them within the message.\n}\n",
                            null, false, null);
        }

        CompilationUnitEditor editor = activeCompilationUnitEditor();
        editor.setSelection(mtd);
```

My main goal is to add a button that once it's clicked it opens a text box, than it adds a function with the given text to the current class.
Error if nothing has been typed.

Thank you very much in advanced.

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development would be a better place for plug-in development questions.

Comment: No one responses, can anyone here help please?